# Escaping xml tags inside xml

Tags: xml, perl

I have python script that parse xml file and execute commands. I want my `xml` to read another xml file and edit it. For that i used perl command

```
"perl -pi -0777 -e 's@<en:TagName>.*?</en:TagName>@<en:TagName>new-value</en:TagName>@sg'FileName.xml"
```

This i have added in my xml file that is parsed by shell script.

```
<cmd>perl -pi -0777 -e 's@<en:TagName>.*?</en:TagName>@<en:TagName>new-value</en:TagName>@sg'FileName.xml</cmd>
```

here my python script is treating `<en:TagName>` as a tag and is not able to parse it. So i added `"perl -pi -0777 -e 's#&lt;en:TagName&gt;.*?&lt;en:TagName&gt;#&lt;en:tagName&gt;new-value&lt;/en:TagName&gt;#sg' FileName.xml"`  and also used "#" as delimiter(as @ is special character in shell script that we are using)

Putting # is not able to provide desired result. Instead of replacing it is appending new value at the end.

Comment: You could try putting the perl command in `CDATA` tags. Anything inside a `CDATA` tag is ignored by xml parsers

Comment: @RobEarl : Yes CDATA tag worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surround your perl commands with [`CDATA`](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) tags:

```
Some text, like JavaScript code, contains a lot of "<" or "&" characters. To avoid errors script code can be defined as CDATA.

Everything inside a CDATA section is ignored by the parser.

A CDATA section starts with "<![CDATA[" and ends with "]]>"
```

Comment: +1 that's the proper way (but what if the embedded xml contains a CDATA block?)